# HTML5 Image Preview Not Working On Cloned File Input (Does on Original)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ecmascript-6

What I am trying to do is have a modal form which contains a file input along with various other form fields, then, once the modal form is submitted, the file input, as well as other form elements, are then moved to the main form I want to eventually submit and I then reset the form and replace the original file input with a clone of the original in order to accept further entries.

Everything works perfectly fine except that the html 5 image preview doesn't work on any cloned file inputs, so it only works on the original file input that's present on page load and not any subsequent inputs.

I've tried changing the event handler as well as recalling `handleImages` once the clone is added to the DOM but neither seemed to make a difference and I can't think of what to try next.

I've made a [codpen](http://codepen.io/martincarlin87/pen/egYMmw) and the code is also below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <form action="" class="form-inline" id="image-form">

    <label class="btn btn-info upload-button">
      Tap to Select Images

      <input type="file" style="display: none" multiple accept="image/*" capture="camera">
    </label>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save-image">Save Images</button>

    <div class="preview">
      <div class="row">
      </div>
    </div>

  </form>

  <div id="saved-images" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var imageCount = 0;

var ImageUpload = function() {

    var handleImages = function() {

        document.querySelector('#image-form input[type="file"]').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);

        // also tried
        // $(document).on('change', '#image-form input[type="file"]', handleFileSelect);
    }

    var handleFileSelect = function(e) {

        if ( !e.target.files || !window.FileReader) return;

        var $element = $(e.srcElement).closest('form').find('.preview > .row');
        $element.empty();

        var $srcElement = $(e.srcElement);

        var files = e.target.files;
        var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);

        filesArr.forEach(function(f) {

            if (!f.type.match("image.*")) {
                return;
            }

            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {

                var html = `
                  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumbnail m-t m-b m-r m-l">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="${e.target.result}" alt="${f.name}">
                    <div class="title bg-success">${f.name}</div>
                  </div>
                `;


                $element.append(html);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        });

    }

    var handleSaveImage = function() {

        $(document).on('click', '#save-image', function(f) {

          // Clone the "real" input element
          var $real = $('#image-form input[type="file"]');
          var $clone = $real.clone(true);

          /* Also tried:
            var $clone = $real.clone(false);
            handleImages();

           and
            var $clone = $real.clone(true).val('');
          */

          // Put the cloned element directly after the real element
          $clone.insertAfter($real);

          // change the name and class of the real input
          $real.addClass(`image-${imageCount}`);

          // Move the real element 
          $real.appendTo('#saved-images');

          imageCount++;

          resetImageForm();
      });
  }

  var resetImageForm = function() {
      $('#image-form').trigger('reset');
      $('#image-form .preview').empty();
  }

  return {
      // main function to initiate the module
      init: function() {
          handleImages();
          handleSaveImage();
      }

  };


}();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    ImageUpload.init();
});
```

If I change the event listener to `$(document).on('change', '#image-form input[type="file"]', handleFileSelect);` then the preview code is reached every time but there's no preview, here's a forked version to show what I mean [enter link description here](http://codepen.io/martincarlin87/pen/NdWeNK)

Comment: I have to say I'm not sure what the problem is. It's just not apparent. Can you describe it better or set up a more obvious example?

Comment: Hi Serg, sure. If you select an image in the file upload then 'save', it clones it to make a replacement then moves that input to somewhere else. If you then repeat the process with the cloned element, everything works except the image preview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seen your code and here is solution
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ond09rvh/2/)

```
use $(e.target) instead of $(e.srcElement)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, just checked out the fiddle and it seems to have the same issue (no preview after the first 'save')? I will try it out locally in just a few minutes though. EDIT - yip, still seems to be the same unfortunately.

Comment: Now check again in jsfiddle 

there is issue in $('#image-form .preview').empty(); 


target will $('#image-form .preview .row').empty();

https://jsfiddle.net/ond09rvh/3/